# How do i fix Premature end of script headers and No such file or directory: exec of './.py' error

Tags: python, apache, cgi, mamp

I did look through the similar question but had no luck with my program

here is my program

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Import modules for CGI handling
import cgi, cgitb
# Create instance of FieldStorage
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
# Get data from fields
device_id = form.getvalue('updateDeviceId')
manufact  = form.getvalue('updateManufactureId')
polling_add = form.getvalue('updatePollingAddress')
expand  = form.getvalue('updateExpDev')
loop_control = form.getvalue('updateLoopControl')
message  = form.getvalue('updateMessage')
descriptor = form.getvalue('updateDescriptor')
long  = form.getvalue('updateLongTag')
short = form.getvalue('updateShortTag')
date  = form.getvalue('updateDate')
hardware = form.getvalue('updateHardware')
software  = form.getvalue('updateSoftware')
device = form.getvalue('updateDevice')
protocol_major  = form.getvalue('updateProtocolMajor')
master_slave = form.getvalue('updateMS')
final  = form.getvalue('updateFinal')

print("Content-type: text/html")
print("")
print("")
print("The values are")
print("")
print("")
print("
Hello %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s
" % (device_id, manufact, polling_add, expand, loop_control, message, 
descriptor, long, short, date, hardware, software, device, 
protocol_major, master_slave, final))
print("")
print("")
```

I am using MAMP to run the apache server. I have given the chmod 755 permisssion on the .py file.

Below is my httpd.conf file

```
<Directory "/Applications/MAMP/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI
    Order allow,deny
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .py
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is this print statement:

```
print("
Hello %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s
" % (device_id, manufact, polling_add, expand, loop_control, message, 
descriptor, long, short, date, hardware, software, device, 
protocol_major, master_slave, final))
```

In Python, multi-line strings are enclosed by [triple quotes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings):

```
print("""
Hello %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s
""" % (device_id, manufact, polling_add, expand, loop_control, message, 
descriptor, long, short, date, hardware, software, device, 
protocol_major, master_slave, final))
```